# CREATE/ALTER syntax for SQL Server stored procs in replication scenario?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I store all of my T-SQL DDL statements in a Visual Studio database project under version control.  The scripts are meant to always run without error, so they include a drop/create syntax like so:

```
use MyDatabase
go
if objectproperty(object_id('dbo.MyProcName'), 'IsProcedure') = 1 begin
    drop procedure dbo.MyProcName as
end
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- $Id: $
-- Notes: blah blah
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
create procedure dbo.MyProcName as
--...
go
```

Trouble is, we've moved to a replication scenario so I can no longer use my drop/create syntax because you cannot drop objects marked for replication.  Now I need to create the proc if it doesn't exist, or alter it if it does.  And I can't reverse my `IF` logic because I can't create a proc within an `IF` statement - I can only drop it.  Any ideas?

---

EDIT:
Thanks to Adam's answer, here's what I wound up using.  Don't know why I didn't consider executing a SQL string... must drink more coffee.

```
use MyDatabase
go
if objectproperty(object_id('dbo.MyProcName'), 'IsProcedure') is null begin
    exec('create proc dbo.MyProcName as')
end
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- $Id: $
-- Notes: blah blah
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
alter procedure dbo.MyProcName as
    --...
go
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is have the first portion of your script create a stub for the procedure if it doesn't exist, then turn the rest of the script into an `ALTER` script instead of a `CREATE`.

For example:

```
if objectproperty(object_id('dbo.MyProcName'), 'IsProcedure') <> 1 begin
    exec sp_ExecuteSql N'create Procedure dbo.MyProcName as select 1'
end
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- $Id: $
-- Notes: blah blah
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
alter procedure dbo.MyProcName as
--...
go
```

Note that you'll have to use `sp_ExecuteSql` (or something equivalent) here, since `create procedure` must be the first statement in a batch.

Comment: Oh my goodness.  I must've just had a complete brain freeze that exec-ing stringy SQL didn't occur to me.  Thank you.

Comment: @mattmc3: You bet; this is what I did when I was working with SQL Server Replication Services a couple of years ago.

Comment: I love this creative solution.  Using it now.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the creation of the stored procedure into an EXEC and you can reverse your if logic:

```
exec (N'create procedure...
```

Answer (score 1):

An example like Adam's answer would be something like:

```
declare @ID int
select @ID = ID from sysobjects where OBJECT_NAME(ID)='Proc1' and USER_NAME(uid) = 'dbo'
if @ID is null
begin
    exec('create procedure dbo.Proc1 as')
end
else
begin
    if OBJECTPROPERTY(@ID,N'IsProcedure')=0 or OBJECTPROPERTY(@ID,N'IsMSShipped')=1
    begin
        RAISERROR('An object called dbo.Proc1 exists in the database, but is of the wrong type',16,1) WITH NOWAIT
    end
end
go
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Proc1]
     /* Body of procedure */
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding Examples for TABLE FUNCTIONS:

```
IF objectproperty(object_id('dbo.udf_MyFunction'), 'IsTableFunction') is null
    EXEC sp_ExecuteSql N'CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_MyFunction () RETURNS @X TABLE (Id int) AS BEGIN RETURN END'
GO
```

and SCALAR FUNCTIONS:

```
IF objectproperty(object_id('dbo.udf_MyFunction'), 'IsScalarFunction') is null
    EXEC sp_ExecuteSql N'CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_MyFunction () RETURNS int AS BEGIN RETURN 0 END'
GO
```